# Get the td without childNodes & without format using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying, with simple_html_dom to get the value of a td, without the child it can have.

```
<td>223 <span class="added-time">ADDED September 14, 2015</span> </td>
```

Is the code I'm extracting.

```
$html = file_get_html($row['address']);
$numberviews = $html->find('td', 5);
$numberviews->childNodes(0)->outertext = '';
echo $numberviews->innertext;
```

The problem is that this code keeps the text format of the page I'm scraping from.

How can I kill the text format & get rid of the childNodes at the same time?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by text format?

Comment: @pguardiario I mean the size of the font and the color.

Comment: That should just give "223". There's no font or color there.